# Re-run JS script on window resize or mobile screen change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are similar questions about this but none answered to the effect I'm looking for.

Basically, I'm building a site with Bootstrap 3, and have some JavaScript that makes each div in a row the same height.

How would I re-run this script on window re-size?

Or is there a better approach? Thanks.

Comment: $(window).resize(function(){});

Comment: just wrap my javascript in it ? Its js but im already calling Jquery lib when page loads

Comment: yes. $(window).resize(function(){  //your code here to run when resized  });